# It seems I can't read the URL for a string

Tags: php

I need a slideshow to be translated, I have made 4 different slideshows to display for each language. However the code I use is always showing 'slideshow-default'.

The URL is like "www.domain.com/en/page" ofcourse "en" can also be "de" or "fr".

```
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $english = 'en';
    $german = 'de';
    $french = 'fr';

    if (strpos ($url, $english) == true) {
        echo 'slideshow1';
    }
    elseif (strpos ($url, $french) == true) {
        echo 'slideshow2';
    }
    elseif (strpos ($url, $german) == true) {
        echo 'slideshow3';
    }
    else {
        echo 'slideshow-default';
    }
```

Comment: Don't use "==" for strpos try "==="

Comment: What's in `$url` and `$english`.. ?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the URL and how you're setting the variables for the languages?

Comment: `strpos` never returns `true`. it returns either `integer` or `false`. In your code `true` is evaluated as `1`. So you compare `strpos` with `1`

Comment: I dont understand anything. You have to share more details.

Comment: Thanks for answering the "===" doesn't work. I have edited the post, now you can see the variables.

Comment: @Syourt you don't show what $url is - ironically the wrong code in the question would work if the url is of the form `/en/xxx` since strpos would return 1.

Comment: What are the test cases for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ?

Comment: And if the url is `/de/friend`? What larks.... parse the URL properly

Comment: @hindmost This is not true. The integer will be cast to a boolean and compared with `true`. `3 == true` is `true`.

Comment: It would be best to use as `file.php?en` instead of the present method. If the case doesn't exist, then it will go to default instead.

Comment: @AD7six you made a comment on my answer that has now disappeared - something about "false positives"? My example was based on the documentation and what we have used in practice.

Comment: @JayBlanchard as with the question and most answers - it's susceptible to false postivies consider `/en/foo` , `/de/en...`.

Comment: @Syourt you're better of with `$test = substr($url, 0, 4); if ($test === '/en/') { ...` - i.e. don't test if the substring is in the url - get the only relevant substring and look what it is.

Comment: @AD7six Not if [`this method is used`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163048/it-seems-i-cant-read-the-url-for-a-string#comment37292098_24163048) instead of OP's `www.domain.com/en/page` method.

Comment: Ah, thank @AD7six. The problem is that we cannot account for how the OP will form their URL's, we can only answer why their current code doesn't work.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it's in the question.

Comment: The URL returns only "/" instead of the whole URL

Comment: @Fred-ii- IMO that suggestion is an awful/ugly solution.

Comment: @Syourt in that case, the problem you have is not what you've asked it is "why are you requesting the url /" - not enough info -> off topic.

Comment: To a degree @AD7six - what if 'domain.com' were 'friendeasy.com'? Plenty of false positives there. The OP supplied a URL in which one of their strings could be in one place. Perhaps he should change the language variables to start and end with slashes - `/en/`, or `/fr/`? Or even better, do it Fred's way?

Comment: @JayBlanchard the domain isn't in REQUEST_URI - it's only the path (i.e. `/whatever`).

Comment: Agreed @AD7six, but the same conditions apply - it could just as easily be `/en/friendeasy.html`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Maybe there's something I don't know about the usage of the OP's script, which is why I suggested the `file.php?en` method. Do you think that OP is using some form of `mod_rewrite`? Should the OP be using `case` instead? So many questions lol

Comment: I suppose that is the point @Fred-ii-, we can only answer what we see, not what we think might be.

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Ah,* the unknown. Always been a favorite 'o mine. Notice the "Carlin touch"? cheers ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the manual: https://www.php.net/strpos

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
> beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
> that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

so, this is how you do it:

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$english = 'en';
$german = 'de';
$french = 'fr';

if (strpos ($url, $english) !== false) {
    echo 'slideshow1';
}
elseif (strpos ($url, $french) !== false) {
    echo 'slideshow2';
}
elseif (strpos ($url, $german) !== false) {
    echo 'slideshow3';
}
else {
    echo 'slideshow-default';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code more flexible you have to refactor it to work with array.

So your code should look like this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$a_map = array(
    'en' => 'slideshow1',
    'de' => 'slideshow2',
    'fr' => 'slideshow3',
);

$arr = array_filter(
    array_flip($a_map),
    function ($v) use($url) { return strpos($url, $v) !== false; }
);

echo count($arr)? array_pop(array_values($arr)) : 'slideshow-default';
```

Answer (score -1):

strpos will not return `true`. It will either return `false` or an int.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

You can compare against `false`

```
if (false !== strpos ($url, $english))
```

or use a more sophisticates regexp pattern matching.

Comment: ints in PHP are truthy if they are not 0. `3 == true` will be `true`.

Comment: Yes, thats why you should use the === and !== strict operators, as I did.

Answer (score -1):

`strpos` will only return an integer or 'FALSE'. Perform your tests like this -

```
if (strpos ($url, $english) !== FALSE) { // one way
        echo 'slideshow1';
    }
    elseif (strpos ($url, $french) > 0) { // another way
        echo 'slideshow2';
    }
    elseif (strpos ($url, $german) > 0) {
        echo 'slideshow3';
    }
    else {
        echo 'slideshow-default';
    }
```

Using `> 0` is safe here as we're searching a URL string and it would seem to me that it would be safe to assume that the language variable would not be at the front of the string.

Comment: False positives? How so?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. I'll fix that ;-)

Comment: Plus, why was this downvoted if `Latheesan Kanes's` answer wasn't? It's basically the same thing; which I don't get. I don't want to sound mean about it, but it's true.

Comment: @Fred-ii- fixed =). The problem with this question and all answers is it's probably an x/y problem - what's being asked is not likely to be the actual problem - the code in the question would work (with false positives) - the problem is different than described (which is why incidentally I haven't written an answer).

Comment: @AD7six I guess that evens the score then. Is an `"lol"` appropriate here? lol (I'm bad).

Comment: @AD7six I noticed your edit, I guess you were answering in regards to my "why so?" earlier. You have a point there about the `x/y` problem. Yet, why do you feel that using `file.php?en` *"is an awful/ugly solution"*? Just curious.